# Variable name seems to be overwritten

Tags: python, file

So I'm writing a very simple saving system for my game, and it keeps saving the file name as simply the variable name (before the addition of the ":MinecraftText-turePack.txt"). I ran a print through it (after the name change), and the variable was changed, but it still gave me the wrong file name. Any thoughts? Thanks.

```
if response == "save_pack":
    print("What do you want to call it?")
    name = input()
    name = name + ":MinecraftText-turePack.txt"
    pack = open(name, "w")
    for each in inventory:
        name, amount, recipe = each
        pack.write(name)
   pack.close()
```

Edit: Possibly another important detail; it is creating a file, just with the wrong name

Comment: Whats wrong value u are getting for `name` variable ?

Comment: It's just returning what is inputted

Comment: What value has inventory?

Comment: can you give an example that fails?  what input for name gives you unexpected results?

Comment: inventory is a list of tuples, and since input is being inputted, theoretically any example won't work. But just one would be, I don't know, bob, not turning into bob:MinecraftText-turePack.txt

Comment: What system are you running on? Colon might not be valid in a file name. Try without it to see if that works.

Comment: Yep, it was the colon. Silly me, for not knowing that. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `print` statement used as a function I'll assume we're working with Python 3.  Moving the prompt is optional, but removes a line of code.  Also, just for clarity, I've renamed the second `name` variable to `pname` and started a new variable for the filename called `fname`.  This way you can check each one.  Also try taking out the colon in the file name (as Michael suggested)

```
if response == "save_pack":
    name = input("What do you want to call it?\n")
    fname = name + "-MinecraftText-turePack.txt"
    pack = open(fname, "w")
    for each in inventory:
        pname, amount, recipe = each
        pack.write(pname)
   pack.close()
```

Although this answer is slightly more clear, your original example ran from a linux prompt just fine. Most non-unix systems don't like `:` in file names.  Here is some [background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386344/how-to-get-a-file-in-windows-with-a-colon-in-the-filename) for Windows in particular.

Comment: It doesn't seem to recognize raw_input as a valid command. The exact error is: NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: sorry, looks like you're using Python 3 and `raw_input` is not there anymore. What happens if you break up the variables so we can test each one.  For example `name = input()`; `fname = name + ":Minecra..."`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Windows. You have a colon (:) in your file name. That is a reserved character, and actually specifies a file stream.

[File Streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404(v=vs.85).aspx)

Try using a different character in the name.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python-dotenv or any library which imports and overwrites local variables with the environment, the variable name in your top level module will be overwritten by `os.environ['name']` which is the hostname of the machine running the python intepreter. If you didn't set a hostname, it'll be an empty string and therefore `name == ''`.

If you want to make sure that this is what's happening, try to set variable names like `shell`, `pwd`, `user`, etc. on Linux and `homepath`, `appdata`, `windir`, etc. on Windows and see if they're overwritten.