# VBA Excel: list files in backup (prev. version) folder

Tags: excel, vba, windows-7-x64, special-folders

Below is a very simple code for listing files in a specified folder. It works as expected.
However, when I provide one of the backup folders of this folder, it throws invalid path (backup folder path copied from win explorer window).

E.g.: 
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:\Test")** 'works well
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:\Test (2015.2.12 3:12 PM)") 'not work. this is a previous/backup version of folder test created by Win7

Is there a way to list backup folder files with VBA in Excel?

```
Sub Example1()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:\Test")
'Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:\Test (2015.2.12 3:12PM)") throws error

i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'print file name
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
    'print file path
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Path
    i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

How backup folders look like:

[image]
[image]
[image]

When I copy the  path and paste it, some ? chars appear in the brackets:
\localhost\C$\Users\IBALLA1\Downloads (?Friday, ?April ?17, ?2015, ??9:05 AM)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use colons in file names or folders names.  The : in the time you have in a folder name can't be create and can't already be there.  I don't know if that's a typo in your question or not though.

Comment: No, this is the format Win7 creates the backups. Unfortunately I have no mean to change this. Backup folder names will contain colon. Is there a way to normalize and refer to the backup folder? Thank you

Comment: Beyond me now.  I think the colon is your issue still but I don't know how to fix it.  Is is possible it's another character that looks like a colon but is actually something else?  See the 2nd and 3rd answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386344/how-to-get-a-file-in-windows-with-a-colon-in-the-filename

Comment: I uploaded some screenshots. any char it is in the brackets, the script cannot list that folde's files