# How to copy a file with a timestam

Tags: python

I would like to save in a variable the current time (I can do this)
I then want to copy file a to file b and include the timestamp in file b.
like this copy file1 file1.08-02-2019 (like a backup of the file)
I can copy the file fine except when I add the timestamp?

I can do the copy with no issues. I just can't get the copy to work with the timestamp variable in the dest file name

```
import shutil
import datetime
import os

now = datetime.datetime.now()
timestamp = str(now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S"))

os.system('copy C:\\Users\\kwhol\\my_python_code\\twp_pid_ctrl, C:\\Users\\kwhol\\my_python_code\\twp_pid_ctrl_backup'+'timestamp')
```

it takes the time stamp as literal meaning the word timestamp is in the dest file name not the actual value of the timestamp variable

Comment: In windows no `:` is allowed as part of the filename, only as drive-delimiter ...

Comment: You add the text `'timestamp'` to your filename - not your variables content

Comment: @PatrickArtner I think you have mistakenly marked this as duplicate. Please read the question carefully. "*I can do the copy with no issues. I just can't get the copy to work with the timestamp variable in the dest file name*". So referring posts on `how to rename a file` or `how to copy a file` in python does not do the justice to OP. Kindly, remove the duplicate marker.

Comment: @five I added some more duplicates - there are about 5 to 10 others floating around with answers. Probably closest to this users problem (after fixing using the _variable_ instead of a string of the variable-name is [Adding timestamp to a file in PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736080/adding-timestamp-to-a-file-in-python). All solve the underlying problem by telling him how to fix his code to create a file with a timestamp in it. If not a duplicate this would probably be a "Close due to typo" kind of question that should not have answers at all...

Answer (score 0):

You can't have colons in filenames. Use some other delimeter, like a period.
Also `C:\\Users\\kwhol\\my_python_code\\twp_pid_ctrl_backup'+'timestamp'`

`timestamp` shouldn't be in quotes, as this makes it a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the below. Make sure to format your timestamp
appropriately so it can be supported in the filename by OS.

```
import shutil 
import datetime 
import os

now = datetime.datetime.now() timestamp =
str(now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S"))

src = "C:\\Users\\kwhol\\my_python_code\\twp_pid_ctrl"
dest = "C:\\Users\\kwhol\\my_python_code\\twp_pid_ctrl_backup_"+timestamp
shutil.copy(src, dest)
```

Or the last 3 lines could be replaced by the way you are doing (I am not sure though whether it actually copies):

```
os.system('copy C:\\Users\\kwhol\\my_python_code\\twp_pid_ctrl, C:\\Users\\kwhol\\my_python_code\\twp_pid_ctrl_backup_'+timestamp)
```

Comment: wont work, illegal filename under windows.

Comment: Depends on timestamp format. I would say do not use characters like `:` instead use `_` for hour-minute-second separator.