# How to save a .mat file using a name with a :

Tags: matlab

If I do x='bob:.mat' and then try to save it as a mat file like so:

```
number=10;
save(bob,'number');
```

I get an issue where it can't be saved, and I am assuming this is the case because: is a special character. I looked up online how to use it, and an example told me to put a ' mark before it, but that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I posted an answer too quick. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think the best 'solution' is *don't*, using special characters in filenames is just asking for trouble.  But if you insist, tell us what o/s you are working with, as answers are likely to differ from one to the next.

Comment: You have many questions with useful answers, but have not accepted a single one. Please read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . Upvoting and accepting answers is the way to thank people for their help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be: `save('bob.mat', 'number');`

Or

`save bob number`

`save('bob', 'number');` also works.

`save('bob:', 'number');` results an error (in Windows):

> Error using save
>   Unable to open file "bob:" for output.

A file name with `:` is not allowed, because it's reserved for drive letters like `C:`.

A workaround is described here: [How to get a file in Windows with a colon in the filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386344/how-to-get-a-file-in-windows-with-a-colon-in-the-filename)

Following code actually does work:
`save('bob꞉','number');`

Comment: My bad, I meant that x='bob:.mat' main issue is that I want to use a colon, but it won't let me.

Comment: Colon is not allowed in file names.

Comment: I'm surprised there aren't any fixes for that but thank you. Had no idea.

Comment: Following code actually works: `save('bob꞉','number');`

Comment: Why are you never approving any of the answers to your questions?