# Save a workspace with current time. MAtlab

Tags: matlab, save, save-as

I would like to save all simulation variables ad fig with the current time.

my solution:

```
t = datetime('now','Format','dd-MM-yyyy''_T''HHmmss');
t2 = datevec(t);
DateString = datestr(t2);
filename=[DateString,' all_variables_main '];
save(filename )
savefig(filename)
```

The following error was given in Matlab:

`Unable to write file 26-Oct-2019 09:47:15 all_variables_main : Invalid argument.`

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

File name containing `:` character is not a valid file name.

You can replace the `:` with **"꞉"** character.
See: [How to get a file in Windows with a colon in the filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386344/how-to-get-a-file-in-windows-with-a-colon-in-the-filename)

You can replace all `:` with `꞉` character (unicode character A789 that looks like colon) that is valid to be used in file name.

```
filename(filename == ':') = char(hex2dec('A789'));
```

Make sure to use the right character when loading the file.

Remark: The above solution was tested in Windows 10, and MATLAB R2016a.

Answer (score 1):

`mat` filenames cannot have spaces or colons in them. You can use the following to directly obtain the date and time in a format that is allowed in a filename:

```
>> fileName = [datestr(now, 'dd-mmm-yyyy_HHMMSS') '_all_variables_main']
fileName =
    '26-Oct-2019_103123_all_variables_main'
>> save(fileName)
```