# why is pickle not saving the obj file with different timestamp strings - ctime and strftime?

Tags: python, pickle

I m using pickle to save obj file. Obj file is used to save a model.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dill as pickle
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator

class clf_express(BaseEstimator):
    """
    Base class for model handling
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Assign objects to use in transform() and predict() methods
        """

        #creation_time = pd.Timestamp.now().ctime()
        time = pd.Timestamp.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')
        self.name = "RISK_MODEL_for_credit_card_without_non_logical_created_at_" + time  

    def pickle_myself(self):
        """
        Save class object to binary file
        """
        self.date_create = pd.Timestamp.now().ctime()
        with open(self.name +'.obj', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(self, f, protocol=3)
```

the problem starts with pickle_myself method().

this code works if i use strftime() for timestamp:

```
        time = pd.Timestamp.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M') #this works
        self.name = "RISK_MODEL_for_credit_card_without_non_logical_created_at_" + time
```

and when I call pickle_myself() it works, it does save it and dump as obj file.
the name for my model that i save is:

```
'RISK_MODEL_for_credit_card_without_non_logical_created_at_2019-12-19-17-42'
```

this code does not work if i use ctime() for timestamp:

```
    time = pd.Timestamp.now().ctime()
    self.name = "RISK_MODEL_for_credit_card_without_non_logical_created_at_" + time
```

the name i should have for my model is:

```
'RISK_MODEL_for_credit_card_without_non_logical_created_at_Thu Dec 19 17:42:44 2019'
```

but both strftime and ctime are strings! Why is pickle dump not working?

the error msg:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'RISK_MODEL_for_credit_card_without_non_logical_created_at_Thu Dec 19 17:44:14 2019.obj'
```

Comment: `:` is invalid filename character in your file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with pickle's library, if you look at the error you got it says `OSError: [Errno 22]`.

If you google for this error, you may stumble upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584124/oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument-when-use-open-in-python) question.

Which would lead me to this question: are you on [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386344/how-to-get-a-file-in-windows-with-a-colon-in-the-filename)? Because the file you're trying to write, has colons in its name.

Then the issue is that you're trying to name your file with colons:

```
'RISK_MODEL_for_credit_card_without_non_logical_created_at_Thu Dec 19 17:42:44 2019'
```

doing a `.replace(":", "_")` should be enough for fixing it.

Comment: Just replace colons with something else, for example "_" or dots "." or whatever you like. Just remove the `:`.

Comment: thx u , i realized i m over engineering it. for readability yes , ctime is better - i wanted to use it for this reason.

Comment: @kaban If my answer solved your issue, could you please marked it as solved by accepting it? Thanks