# Open filename with special characters in python from Windows

Tags: python

I have no issue with this on Mac. Windows seems to have trouble opening it.

I have a file name eg : `stdout_blahblah_2020-08-25T00:00:00.000Z_2020-08-26T00:00:00.000Z.txt`

I cant change the file name unfortunately and I have tons of them to open. This is a simple code I wrote:

```
sysout_filename = "stdout_blahblah_2020-08-25T00:00:00.000Z_2020-08-26T00:00:00.000Z.txt"
sys.stdout = open(sysout_filename, "w")
```

So how can I open this file without getting `OSError`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a file in Windows with a colon in the filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386344/how-to-get-a-file-in-windows-with-a-colon-in-the-filename)

Comment: I dont think so. can I use escape? @IainShelvington

Comment: A colon `:` is not a valid character for a windows filename, you will have to use another character in it's place

Comment: The link given solved it. Thanks!