# Problem while trying to save a frame after every 1 second using opencv

Tags: python, path, working-directory

I tried running the code below, it runs successfully but the images are not saved anywhere on the system. Does anyone know where the problem is or the solution?

```
import cv2
import time

# open the default camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# set the width and height of the frame
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

# set the start time
start_time = time.time()

# loop through the frames
print("looping through frames")
while True:
    # capture a frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    t = time.localtime()
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)

    # define the output file name and format
    output_file = f'/Frame_{current_time}.jpg'
    output_format = 'JPEG'

    # check if the frame is captured successfully
    if not ret:
        break

    # calculate the elapsed time
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

    # check if 1 second has passed
    if elapsed_time >= 1:
        print("1 second passed")
        # save the frame as an image file
        cv2.imwrite(f'/TestFrames/{output_file}', frame)
        print(output_file)
        print("image saved")

        # reset the start time
        start_time = time.time()
        print("time reset")

    # display the frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    # check for the 'q' key to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# release the camera and close all windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried running the code below, it runs successfully but the images are not saved anywhere on the system.

Comment: If it doesn't do what it's supposed it, I wouldn't call it "successful". | Are the file names you generate valid? Is the path correct? Does the directory exist? (In this particular case, is there a directory named `TestFrames` at the root of your filesystem?)

Comment: does the `/TestFrames/` directory even exist? if not, why not? that's an absolute path. the directory would have to be in the root of the file system.

Comment: Yes, the directory named `TestFrames` exists in the root directory. The main issue is with the saving of the image.

Comment: Okay so I tried changing the path for saving the image from `cv2.imwrite(f'/TestFrames/{output_file}', frame)` to `cv2.imwrite(output_file, frame)`. The images are getting saved but the only issue is that they are getting saved in `D:\pythonProject1\KnownFaces` instead of `D:\pythonProject1`. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that the image file name contains colon (`:`) characters, and colon character is invalid character (at least for a Windows) file name.

For testing, we may check the returned status of `cv2.imwrite` (status is `True` for success and `False` for failure):

```
is_ok = cv2.imwrite(f'/TestFrames/{output_file}', frame)
print(output_file)

if is_ok:
    print("image saved")
else:
    print("Failed saving the image")
```

---

Assuming we are using Windows:

We may replace the `:` characters with `_` for example:

```
output_file = f'Frame_{current_time}.jpg'
output_file = output_file.replace(":", "_")
```

---

The [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25477235/4926757) recommends to replace the colon with a unicode character "**꞉**" that looks like colon, but `cv2.imwrite` doesn't support unicode characters (at least not in Windows).

In case we want to use the '`\ua789`' unicode character we may use `cv2.imencode` and binary file writing:

```
with open(f'/TestFrames/{output_file}', 'wb') as f:  # Open image file as binary file for writing
    cv2.imencode('.'+output_format, frame)[1].tofile(f)  # encode the image as JPEG, and write the encoded image to the file (use [1] because cv2.imencode returns a tuple).
```

---

Code sample that uses the unicode character instead of colon:

```
import cv2
import time

# open the default camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# set the width and height of the frame
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

# set the start time
start_time = time.time()

# loop through the frames
print("looping through frames")
while True:
    # capture a frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    t = time.localtime()
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)

    # define the output file name and format
    output_file = f'Frame_{current_time}.jpg'
    output_file = output_file.replace(":", "\ua789")  # Replace colon character with a character that looks like colon
    #output_file = output_file.replace(":", "_")  # Replace colon character with a underscore character
    output_format = 'JPEG'

    # check if the frame is captured successfully
    if not ret:
        break

    # calculate the elapsed time
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

    # check if 1 second has passed
    if elapsed_time >= 1:
        print("1 second passed")

        # save the frame as an image file
        #is_ok = cv2.imwrite(f'/TestFrames/{output_file}', frame)

        with open(f'/TestFrames/{output_file}', 'wb') as f:  # Open image file as binary file for writing
            cv2.imencode('.'+output_format, frame)[1].tofile(f)  # encode the image as JPEG, and write the encoded image to the file (use [1] because cv2.imencode returns a tuple).

        print(output_file)
        print("image saved")

        # reset the start time
        start_time = time.time()
        print("time reset")

    # display the frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    # check for the 'q' key to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# release the camera and close all windows
cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I tried the above method but the image isn't getting saved in the system. I used the `if is_ok` block to detect it. Replacing the colon with underscore didn't allow the image to be saved. And I also tried the **wb** method but since the image is not saved, the **wb** method can't overwrite the `output_file`. Do you have any other solutions for this problem?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux or Mac (or other OS)?

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: According to your other comments, it looks like `TestFrames` is inside `D:\pythonProject1`, and not in the "root" (not in `D:\TestFrames`). What is the full path of `TestFrames`? Is it `D:\TestFrames` or `D:\pythonProject1\TestFrames` or somewhere else?

Comment: The full path of `TestFrames` is `D:\pythonProject1\TestFrames`.

Comment: I looks like you intended to use **relative path** but used absolute path instead. Replace `cv2.imwrite(f'/TestFrames/{output_file}', frame)` with `cv2.imwrite(f'../TestFrames/{output_file}', frame)`. The `../` means going one level up from `D:\pythonProject1\KnownFaces` to `D:\pythonProject1`, and then from `D:\pythonProject1` to `D:\pythonProject1\TestFrames`.